# Setting a dynamic value as header in subseqent request Gatling/Scala

Tags: scala, http, header, token, gatling

I have regex'ed a value that I want to use for subsequent requests in my Gatling script this way:

```
 .exec(http("request_test")
    .get("https://test/eai/bad")
    .check(regex("content=\"([0-9A-Z]*)\"").saveAs("bidkid")))
```

Now in the receeding request I want to add bidkid as a header to the request. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
.exec(http("request_test")
  .get("https://test/eai/bad")
  .check(regex("content=\"([0-9A-Z]*)\"").saveAs("bidkid")))
.pause(2)
.exec(http("Next Request")
  .get("https://test/eai/bad")
  .header("header_name", "${bidkid}")
```

It should work.